# Using Email Template in Spring

Tags: spring

I am developing a small utility application emailafriend using Spring. The basic functionality is to email the current url to a friend. As of now I am using a fixed email template which I have hard coded in the class something like -

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(form.getSenderName());
buf.append(" want to look at this page: ").append("\n\n<");
buf.append("http://").append(host).append(form.getPageUrl()).append(">\n\n");
buf.append("Please click on the link above for more information.");
buf.append("\n\n");
```

But, the email templates can be changed frequently as per business. Can I utilize spring for this purpose (or any other way), so that I don't have to the Java code again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a template engine such as [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) for this (or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/), but Freemarker is better, IMO).  Spring [provides support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/view.html#view-velocity) for these.

Comment: Thanks. I would appreciate if you can provide some link which describes Freemarker in detail with some example.

Comment: I provided a link to Freemarker, and there is plenty of documentation and examples on it.